# Laravel stripe payment form isn't handled just posted

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I'm using the default card element from Stripe which can be found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart). The form renders and the validation stripe includes works & renders. However, I never get a `stripeToken` generated so the subscription fails due to;

```
This customer has no attached payment source
```

When I die dump my requests the `stripeToken` is `NULL`. I think this is because the stripe form handler doesn't work at all for me, the event listener they include doesn't ever fire.

Looks like the form is just posting like a normal form instead of the prevent default JS listener added by stripe.

```
<form action="{{ route('subscriptionCreate') }}" method="post" id="payment-form">
  @csrf
  <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="{{ $plan->id }}">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

The Javascript included from the elements example;

```
<script>

// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('###Removed###');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});


// // Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
</script>
```

This is my controller, as I mentioned the `$request->stripeToken` doesn't exist I don't think it ever gets added to the form.

```
public function create(Request $request)
{

    $plan = Plan::findOrFail($request->get('plan'));

    $user = $request->user();

    $request->user()
        ->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->stripe_plan)
        ->create($request->stripeToken,[
            'email' => $user->email
        ]);

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Your plan subscribed successfully');
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console after pressing the submit button and before submitting the form?

Comment: @Markus no errors are displayed

Comment: I have the exact same issue, with Laravel as well. I cannot get this to work at all and it's really bugging me. Would love if someone could help find a solution to this...

Comment: Do you get the card displayed, I've integrated more than 11 payment gateways and would be more than happy to help

Comment: I just need to get more information so I can help you better, at first let me know if you can insert credit card details

Comment: yes, you can enter the card details the form from stripe elements renders. Also the client-side validation on the form from Stripe works which is in the JS above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A default Laravel installation will include an `app.js` file. By simply removing or commenting out this file from being included in your header allows Stripe to generate the token using Stripe Elements.

Answer (score 4):

I've created https://jsfiddle.net/s8foxw9r/2/ that confirms the `stripeTokenHandler` is working (and the token is being generated correctly).

If you open the jsfiddle URL, then open the developer tools in your browser and look at the console output you will see a dump of the `token` object that is passed to `stripeTokenHandler()`.

When you hit `Submit Payment` the page `POST`s to https://postman-echo.com/post which will dump out your request.  You'll notice the request looks something like this:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "stripeToken": "tok_1F07d72eZvKYlo2CqBprboVK"
  },
  "headers": {
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "host": "postman-echo.com",
    "content-length": "40",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cookie": "sails.sid=s%3AHyTHsNyIhRvFINR3EGiXw1Kf12oufx84.jd6rEiCaqHsrM8eOGN1x%2ByzU%2BMatjM4l5S1Ekxhxdyo",
    "origin": "https://fiddle.jshell.net",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "referer": "https://fiddle.jshell.net/",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36",
    "x-forwarded-port": "443"
  },
  "json": {
    "stripeToken": "tok_1F07d72eZvKYlo2CqBprboVK"
  },
  "url": "https://postman-echo.com/post"
}
```

The important parts are `headers.content-type` and `json` attributes.  This means the stripe.js lib `POST`ed the form via the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type, and that the `stripeToken` was included.

This means your issue is one/both of the following:

1. If you are not seeing a token generated in the browser, your stripe private key is probably incorrect.  I'd start out with using your stripe test private key, it looks like `pk_test_xxx`.
2. Your Laravel server is not setup correctly.  Lots of potential issues, would need more info, and unfortunately I've never used Laravel.

Lastly, I found a Stripe integration package for Laravel, might be worth trying: https://github.com/cartalyst/stripe-laravel

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before
this is how it worked for me:

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

then update the env file with your keys

```
STRIPE_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
STRIPE_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

then with your controller

```
use Stripe;
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $plan = Plan::findOrFail($request->get('plan'));
        $user = $request->user();
        $request->user()
        ->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->stripe_plan);
       // getting the plan cost
        $amount = $plan->plan_amount;

        Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        Stripe\Charge::create ([
                "amount" => ($amount * 100),
                "currency" => "usd",
                "source" => $request->stripeToken,
                "description" => "Test payment" 
        ]);
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Your plan subscribed successfully');
     }
```

Comment: In your example you have `newSubscription` and `Stripe\Charge` surely you wouldn't have both or this an example of a one-off payment and subscription?